# messaging.sh: line 29: [: missing `]'

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I don't know if this is a bad thing, or what it means. My script still seems to work fine, but should I fix it?

```
#!/bin/sh
#This script will send text and maybe images to other computers via ssh and scp.
#Configuration files in same folder

source /Users/jacobgarby/Desktop/messaging/messages.cfg
TIME=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
CONNECTED[0]="mainmini@192.168.1.65"

if [ -d messages.log ]; then
    :
else
    touch messages.log
fi

read MSG

if [ "$MSG" == "!help" ]; then
    echo ; echo "!clear   Clear's your personal chat log."
    echo "!ban [usrname]    Prevents a user from entering this chat IN DEV."
else
    echo "$TIME | $USER | $MSG" >> messages.log; echo   >> messages.log; echo   >> messages.log
    tail messages.log
fi

for CONNECTION in CONNECTED; do
    echo "It works"
done

if [ "alerttype" == "notification"]; then
    osascript -e 'display notification "You have recieved a message!" with title "Message"'
else
    osascript -e 'display dialog "You have recieved a message!" with title "Message"'
fi
```

Comment: Belongs on Linux/Unix site

Comment: The string `alerttype` will never be the same as the string `notification`. Perhaps you mean `[ "$alerttype" = "notification" ]`?

Comment: (and yes, I mean `=`, not `==` -- see the POSIX specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, and you'll see that the supported string comparison syntax is `s1 =  s2`; `==` is a bash extension, and not all operating systems and shells will support it; if you want to use an explicitly bash-extended comparison operator rather than the POSIX-standard one, that's `[[ ]]`, not `[ ]`).

Comment: Yeah, since I posted this I realized that

Comment: Also, having a whole bunch of separate commands with `>> messages.log` is inefficient, since each one reopens the output file. Don't do that. `printf '%s\n\n\n' "$TIME | $USER | $MSG" >>messages.log` prints the line you want and two trailing newlines all at once. (Also, there's no need for the `touch`; the `>>` operator will create the file if it doesn't exist itself).

Comment: ...or you can `exec 5>>messages.log` up at the top of your script to open the file for append, and `echo "something" >&5` to append it via the already-open file handle. (`5` is just an arbitrary FD number; anything in the range 3-9 is guaranteed to be safe for use in POSIX-compliant shells, and in newer operating systems and shells much higher FD numbers are typically valid too).

Comment: Also, `CONNECTED[0]=something` is syntax not guaranteed to work in POSIX shells. Change your shebang from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` if you want bash-only syntax to be guaranteed to work... or if you want to use bash arrays correctly, make it `connected=( mainmini@192.168.1.65 )` and, later, `for connection in "${connected[@]}"` to iterate over them.

Comment: ...and, yes, the use of lower-case variable names is deliberate and in line with best practices. See the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace: "The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities."

Comment: In short, if you stick to lower-case variable names for your own variables, you won't overwrite any all-uppercase variable that modifies shell or system behavior by mistake. (There are a few places where the distinction where user and system variable namespaces gets blurry, as with proxy configuration, but those are a small number of isolated cases).

Comment: These sort of errors can be easily found with: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### messaging.sh: line 29: [: missing ']'

You are using the following:

```
if [ "alerttype" == "notification"]; then`
```

However, the above command is missing a `space` before `]`, it should be:

```
if [ "alerttype" == "notification" ]; then
                                  ^
```

---

#### The basic rules of conditions

> > When you start writing and using your own conditions, there are some rules you should know to prevent getting errors that are hard to
> >     trace. Here follow three important ones:
>
> 1. Always keep spaces between the brackets and the actual check/comparison. The following won’t work:
>
>    `if [$foo -ge 3]; then`
>
>    Bash will complain about a "missing ']'".

Source [Conditions in bash scripting (if statements)](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/)

Comment: I think Steven just said this, but you're right

Comment: Yeah, we answered around the same time ... I took longer because I wanted to look up and quote a reference for the correct syntax :/

Comment: I know, I would upvote both but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: You seem to be half way to the "comment" privilege ;)

Comment: It's more wrong than that. Even as `[ "alerttype" == "notification" ]`, it's comparing two constants, meaning it will **never** be true.  Perhaps one end or the other side should be a variable reference? Also, `==` isn't in the POSIX spec for `test`; to be portable, it needs to be `=`.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a single space.

```
#BEFORE
if [ "alerttype" == "notification"]; then
#AFTER
if [ "alerttype" == "notification" ]; then
#                                 ^
```

Another example:

```
$ if [ "a" == "a"]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
-bash: [: missing `]'
no

$ if [ "a" == "a" ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
yes
```

Comment: It's more wrong than that. Even as `[ "alerttype" == "notification" ]`, it's comparing two constants, meaning it will **never** be true. Also, `==` isn't in the POSIX spec for `test`; to be portable, it needs to be `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Missing the space before the `]`  Also another format option is:

```
$ [ "a" == "a" ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```