# BASH string manipulation, syntax errors

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script

```
./script: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory enter ip
>>> : 10.000

10.00 0 ./script: line 8: [0!=.]: command not found ./script: line 13: =: command not found
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
var="0/24"
echo "enter ip"
read -p ">>> : " ipaddr
echo ${temp}        
echo ${ipaddr%?}                    #display whole string except last character
echo ${ipaddr:(-1)}                 #display last character in string
while [${ipaddr:(-1)}!="."]     #loop till ${ipaddr} last == "."
do
    ${cur} = ${ipaddr::-1}
    echo $cur
done                                    #remove last char if != "." 
$temp = ${ipaddr}${var}         #add string ${var} to end of ${ipaddr}
echo ${temp}
```

Comment: `while [ ${ipaddr:(-1)}!="." ]` fixes the first error. Note the extra space after `[` and before `]`

Comment: thanks for the response, any reason why these spaces are necassary?

Comment: Because the bash condition syntax is defined that way. See my answer [messaging.sh: line 29: \[: missing \`\]'](http://superuser.com/a/927163) for a nice link for you to read.

Comment: I've no idea how to fix the second error. It is not very clear what you are trying to do, and I'm not a `bash` expert.

Comment: what i am trying to accomplish, stated by comments, is read in ip address from user input, remove the last digits till i have the form "x.x.x." then add ${var} to itso it becomes x.x.x.0/24

Comment: for what it is worth, i started bash earlier today, rather finally decided to stop procrastinating and just do it

Comment: Like I said I don't know how to fix your second error. Please wait for someone who knows more about bash scripting to come along.

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have enough rep to add these as comments to the existing answers, I will just write a new answer.

- Assignment of values to a variable in BASH uses just the variable's name, without the `$`-sign. So use `foo="something"`, and NOT `$foo="something"`.
- `[` is an abbreviation of the program/command `test`. Commands take their arguments seperated by spaces. By omitting the space after `[`, you are telling BASH to interpret the whole set of characters as one word/string. While with the space, the `rest of the line` gets passed as an argument to the command `test`. When invoked with `[` however, `test` expects one of its arguments to be `]`, and will complain if that is missing. So use `if [ -f /etc/motd ]` and NOT `if [-f /etc/motd]`

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange!  Good job on your first answer; I think it's good that you explained some basics of the language (`bash`) rather than just fixing the problems with the specific code.  :)  Check out the tour page—http://superuser.com/tour—comments are for comments, not answers, so posting this as an answer is not a bad thing at all.

Comment: These would have served fine as a comment on the below answer by Archenar, that does fix the code and give a brief explanation. I just wanted to further clarify. (finally got the rep to comment ;) )

Answer (score 1):

change revelant lines to

```
while [ ${ipaddr:(-1)} != "." ]     #loop till ${ipaddr} last == "."
do
    cur=${ipaddr::-1}
    echo $cur
done                                    #remove last char if != "." 
temp=${ipaddr}${var}         #add string ${var} to end of ${ipaddr}
```

- in test, you must use space ( because `[${ipaddr:(-1)}!="."]` is interpreted by bash as a single word)  Space after `[` and before `]` and a space on each side of the operator `!=`.
- in variable assignment, do not use `${var}` on the left hand side, but directly `var=EXPR`.  (On the right hand side you use a dollar sign `$` to refer to the value of the variable.)